# The code is working not properly

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

```
%clear workspace
    clear;
    clc;
    close all;
%read Reference image and convert into single
    rgb1= im2single(imread('r1.jpg'));
    I1 = rgb2gray(rgb1);
%create mosaic background
    sz= size(I1)+300;% Size of the mosaic
    h=sz(1);
    w=sz(2);
%create a world coordinate system
    outputView = imref2d([h,w]);
%affine matrix
    xtform = eye(3);
% Warp the current image onto the mosaic image
%using 2D affine geometric transformation
    mosaic = imwarp(rgb1, affine2d(xtform),'OutputView', outputView);
    figure,imshow(mosaic,'initialmagnification','fit');
%read Target image and convert into single
    rgb2= im2single(imread('t1.jpg'));
    I2 = rgb2gray(rgb2);
%find surf features of reference and target image ,then find new 
%affine matrix
%Detect SURFFeatures in the reference image
    points = detectSURFFeatures(I1);
%detectSURFFeatures returns information about SURF features detected 
%in the 2-D grayscale input image . The detectSURFFeatures function 
%implements the Speeded-Up Robust Features (SURF) algorithm 
%to find blob features
%Extract feature vectors, also known as descriptors, and their 
%corresponding locations
    [featuresPrev, pointsPrev] = extractFeatures(I1,points);
%Detect SURFFeatures in the target image
    points = detectSURFFeatures(I2);
%Extract feature vectors and their corresponding locations
    [features, points] = extractFeatures(I2,points); 
% Match features computed from the refernce and the target images
    indexPairs = matchFeatures(features, featuresPrev);  
% Find corresponding locations in the refernce and the target images
    matchedPoints     = points(indexPairs(:, 1), :);
    matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrev(indexPairs(:, 2), :);  
%compute a geometric transformation from the  corresponding locations
    tform=estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPoints,matchedPointsPrev,'affine');
%get affine matrix
    xtform = tform.T;
% Warp the current image onto the mosaic image
    mosaicnew = imwarp(rgb2, affine2d(xtform), 'OutputView', outputView);
    figure,imshow(mosaicnew,'initialmagnification','fit');
%create a object to overlay one image over another
    halphablender = vision.AlphaBlender('Operation', 'Binary mask', 'MaskSource', 'Input port');
% Creat a mask which specifies the region of the target image.
% BY Applying geometric transformation to image
    mask= imwarp(ones(size(I2)), affine2d(xtform), 'OutputView', outputView)>=1;
    figure,imshow(mask,'initialmagnification','fit');
%overlays one image over another
    mosaicfinal = step(halphablender, mosaic,mosaicnew, mask);
% %show results
    figure,imshow(rgb1,'initialmagnification','fit');
    figure,imshow(rgb2,'initialmagnification','fit');
    figure,imshow(mosaicfinal,'initialmagnification','fit');
```

There was an error when using the function 'imref2d' and this is the error that appeared.

`Undefined function 'imref2d' for input arguments of type 'double'. Error in immosaic (line 13) outputView = imref2d([h,w]);`

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d-class.html) manual will help you. You are using incorrect input in `imref2d`.